# IllegalStateException when .replace fragment on restart

Tags: android, android-fragments, illegalstateexception

I am using `FragmentTransaction.replace()` to swap fragments in and out. 
The app starts up first time with no problem. 
An `IllegalStateException` is thrown when rotating the device because of a conflict between the savedInstanceState
and commiting a new fragment transaction.
No AsyncTask is involved.

One StackOverflow question suggests to put the `setContentView()` call
in `onResumeFragments()`, but this seems to have no effect. Same with `onPostResume()`.

Another StackOverflow question says to override `onConfigurationChanged()`. This works in that sense that it the exception doesn't occur
because the Activity is not restarted. However, this prevents fragments that have different portrait
and landscape layouts from switching between these layouts. Calling `setContentView()` in `onConfigurationChanged()` 
causes a similar error (*IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #25: Duplicate id 0x12345678, tag null, or parent id with another fragment*)

Using `fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss()` instead of `.commit()` causes *IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed*.

How do I get this to work?

More exception info:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start
>   activity ComponentInfo{myapp/myap.MainActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Error
>   inflating class fragment at
>   myapp.MainActivity.onResumeFragments(MainActivity.java:450)
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after
>   onSaveInstanceState at > android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1533)
>   at
>   myapp.fragments.FragmentChange.onFragmentChange(FragmentChange.java:128)
>   at
>   myapp.MainActivity.onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(MainActivity.java:490)
>   at
>   myapp.fragments.NavigationDrawerFragment.selectItem(NavigationDrawerFragment.java:197)
>   at
>   myapp.fragments.NavigationDrawerFragment.onCreate(NavigationDrawerFragment.java:78)
>   at myapp.MainActivity.onResumeFragments(MainActivity.java:450)

The sequence in the code upon rotating the device is:

```
MainActivity.onPause()  
MainActivity.saveInstanceState()  
NavigationDrawerFragment.onSaveInstanceState()  
MainActivity.onStop()
MainActivity.onDestroy()
MainActivity.onCreate()
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
MainActivity.onResumeFragments()
    setContentView()
NavigationDrawerFragment.onCreate()
MainActivity.onNavigationDrawerItemSelected()
     fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...
    }


    @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        ...
        FragmentChangeEvent fragmentChangeEvent = new FragmentChangeEvent(null);
        FragmentChange fragmentChange = FragmentChange.getInstance( getSupportFragmentManager());
        fragmentChange.onFragmentChange(fragmentChangeEvent);
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putString("WORKAROUND_FOR_BUG_19917_KEY", "WORKAROUND_FOR_BUG_19917_VALUE");
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResumeFragments() {
        super.onResumeFragments(); 

        // causes onNavigationDrawerItemSelected() to be called, exception thrown 
        setContentView(myapp.R.layout.activity_main);

        mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(myapp.R.id.navigation_drawer);

        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp( // Set up the drawer
                myapp.R.id.navigation_drawer,
                (DrawerLayout) findViewById(myapp.R.id.drawer_layout));
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        if current fragment is "Individual" { // pseudocode
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); // causes IllegalArgumentException
        }
    }
}
```

NavigationDrawerFragment

```
public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

         SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        mUserLearnedDrawer = sp.getBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, false);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mCurrentSelectedPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION);
            mFromSavedInstanceState = true;
        }

        // Select either the default item (0) or the last selected item.
        selectItem(mCurrentSelectedPosition);
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {

        mCurrentSelectedPosition = position;
        if (mDrawerListView != null) {
            mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(position, true);
        }
        if (mDrawerLayout != null) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
        }
        if (mCallbacks != null) {
            // calls MainActivity.onNavigationDrawerItemSelected() 
            mCallbacks.onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION, mCurrentSelectedPosition);
    }

}
```

FragmentChange

```
public class FragmentChange implements FragmentChangeListener {

      public static FragmentChange getInstance(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new FragmentChange(fragmentManager);
        }
        return instance;
    }

    // constructor
    private FragmentChange(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        mFragmentManager = fragmentManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentChange(FragmentChangeEvent fragmentChangeEvent) {
        ...
        mPosition = fragmentChangeEvent.getPosition();

        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        Fragment fragment = EmployeesVerticalFragment.newInstance();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(myapp.R.id.container, fragment);

        fragmentTransaction.commit(); // IllegalState exception here
        ...
    }
}
```

---

A greatly reduced [form of the project on github](https://github.com/emnrd-ito/ReplaceFragments) which reproduces the IllegalStateException:

Comment: I don't mean to demote your question, but what you're asking has been asked and answered countless of times; granted I didn't look at your code (thanks for posting it, btw) but I believe you'd benefit from reading a little bit more about how FragmentManager, Fragments and Lifecycle works. It's a pain in the butt, it's odd, it had so many bugs that google dedicated an entire session (called What the Fragment?) during Google I/O (which I suggest you watch, it's quite interesting). And then revisit your code to make it less crash-prone. :)

Comment: Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k3IT-IJ0J98

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am aware of previous questions about the IllegalStateException. I have tried suggestions from these and nothing has worked yet. I have now watched the video and I do not know anymore than I did before.

Comment: I am sorry you haven't found the video relevant or helping. The scenario is always similar: when you rotate an activity, it gets destroyed. Before this can happen, onSaveInstance must be called (so it can be recreated later). Fragments are these weird things that somehow have their own lifecycle, kinda tied to the activity but not always, you're trying to operate on a fragment which has no activity (destroyed/being recreated), or (if you override some methods) you're trying to operate on a fragment after its state has been saved. I've a question for you, but next comment because it doesn't fit

Comment: Did you try to create a simple 1 activity - 2 fragment sample project and do the same? If you did, then what complexity does your project have on top of the lifecycle? It should take you 15 minutes to file -> new project and add a couple of fragments, again, I don't mean to say you didn't put time into this, but It's really hard to look at all your isolated source code, full of (irrelevant?) nav drawer code, when all you want (I think) is to be able to swap two fragments on rotation? (am I wrong?)

Comment: I appreciate your thoughts on this. I understand that it is difficult to analyze a problem given isolated source code. The Navigation Drawer code is included because it deals with `savedInstanceState` and because when the user selections from the Navigation Drawer, it ultimately causes `setContent()` to be called. The `IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed`" when using commitAllowingStateLoss() indicates that, when replacing fragments, a reference to the old Activity is still there. If is ultimately the problem, I 
don't know how to address that.

Comment: This may be why using `OnPostResume` or `OnResumeFragments` doesn't fix the problem.
Replacing the fragments on orientation change is only necessary because of the layout change.

Comment: So let's see, you want to replace a fragment once the user taps on the nav drawer or you want to change the layout of the existing fragment when that happens. Does your fragment have a public empty parameterless constructor? (needed)

Comment: I do not explicitly declare one, no.

Comment: As silly as it sounds, you need one… :/

Comment: Ok, I added public empty parameterless constructors, but still get the `IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState`. Darnit. Necessary but not sufficient I suspect.

Comment: Damn. I'm a little busy atm, but if you want, start a chat and we can try other things there.

Comment: I am going to create a simpler project, which will take more than 15 minutes. :)

Comment: :) Excellent idea, then move the discussion to chat and we can test it there.

Comment: I've pushed a reduced form of the project to GitHub. See the link in edited question.

Comment: Nice, I can't look at it today, but I will see what I can do tomorrow. No promises (this week is annoying in the US). Also, I haven't touched Android in a while, so I may be too stupid to find a fix :) but I'll look into it.

Comment: If you prefer, I could turn it out to the wild, so to speak, by putting a bounty on it. I could wait on that until after you look at it tomorrow, then give it to you if you find something.

Comment: I don't mind reputation on SO ;) If you want to bounty, maybe some smart-reputation-inclined user has a faster / better answer. I rather see you find the answer than me worry about SO points :)

Comment: You are most well-mannered person I've encountered on SO.

Comment: Ha, thank you for the compliment. I'm 41, been learning to treat people with more and more respect, a much needed skill in a land of Internet-Born-Anonymous people. :) Anyway, I'll try to look at your project later today, after work.

Comment: I am traveling atm and my Internet connection is really bad. I will try later today (gradle is failing to sync due to timeouts) :/

Comment: Dude, it's the holiday, take it easy on yourself.

Comment: @AlLelopath Have you tried recreating the `FragmentChange` instance in `onCreate` of your activity. As it is now, since you only create one static instance of `FragmentChange` this will hold on to the old `FragmentManager` that can't be used anymore as it's from the old and now destroyed activity.

Comment: @TR4Android: I've just tried this on your suggestion. Unfortunately, it made no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FragmentManager is an

> Interface for interacting with Fragment objects *inside of an Activity*.

It strikes me as a particular bad idea to have save it in a static field and reuse and old FragmentManager for a new activity. This will necessarily lead to *Activity has been destroyed*, when the new activity interact with the manager from the old activity.

In your code, replace

```
FragmentChange.getInstance(getFragmentManager());
```

by

```
new FragmentChange(getFragmentManager());
```

Comment: `getSupportFragmentManager()`

Comment: This fix has been pulled https://github.com/emnrd-ito/ReplaceFragments/commit/abc170548f00767aff68d10141a92f01dcbc34bb

Answer (score 3):

*Some comments*:
I can see you have gone "above and beyond" trying to fix it (and have scanned stackoverflow for many tips).
Your code works the first time (even if you are in landscape b4 starting app).
The rotation fails to inflate the fragment (second time around) (in `activity_main`), and also reports the "commit after save" error (that's weird,how on Earth are we getting 2 fatal errors ? maybe on another thread, or ""save" is killing the inflator, but how can it carry on?).
`NavigationDrawerFragment` has a LOT of important code in it (that normally goes in the Activity).
*Analysis*:
Your `MainActivity` class `extends AppCompatActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {
```

Normally you extend `FragmentActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {
```

This is because you inflate `activity_main`, which contains a `fragment`.

```
setContentView(com.example.replacefragments.R.layout.activity_main);
```

Inheritance:
Activity <- FragmentActivity <- AppCompatActivity <- ActionBarActivity
'<-' means inheritance here.
One reason why you would need to consider FragmentActivity specifically is if you want to use nested fragments (a fragment holding another fragment), as that was not supported in native fragments until API Level 17.
I think this is what you are doing here (in `activity_main`):

```
<fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer
```

Here is a good template app that should make your life easier:
[android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/)
***FIXING IT***:
Replace the fragment in `activity_main.xml` with the `ListView`.
I have discarded `NavigationDrawerFragment`, and injected some code from  the template above, then re-introduced bit-by-bit your code from `NavigationDrawerFragment`, until it falls over.
It now works with rotation, but not as you or I would like (preserving fragment state, `NavigationDrawerFragment` some functionality), so I'm still working on it.

protrait
[image: protrait]
landscape after rotation
[image: landscape after rotation]

***Hot tip***:
The `.commit` sounds final does it not ? Sounds as if it should synchronous? Neither are true.
The `.commit` puts the transaction in a pending queue, to truly execute it you need:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
```

Here's a link to the error log of the posted code on rotation:
[link error log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40808394/is-it-possible-for-an-android-app-to-report-two-fatal-errors-as-it-fails)

Answer (score 2):

Method 1. Avoid config changes. Add `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|screenLayout|keyboardHidden|keyboard"` in you manifest activity.

```
<activity
            android:name=".ui.accounts.YouActivity"
          android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|screenLayout|keyboardHidden|keyboard"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
```

Method 2.
a. First of all do not miss place code from default places like `setContentView()` in `onConfigurationChanged()`. 

b. Replace fragment with tag or by id in xml

c. Don't replace again if fragment found by id or tag.

d. Make sure you are dismissing any dailog inside fragment `onPause`.